# QGIS report based on defined labels

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geotiff-tiff

I want to generate a report to see how much area are falling within the range that I have set for the labels. I have tried with the r.report, but it doesn't seem to have a function that I can manage the label range. Does anyone know where I can set it? Or should I be using other report? I'm using QGIS 3.24.1

In this case, I want the report to output area that falls in 4 different range:
<= 0.2 
0.2 - 0.5
0.5 - 0.7 
and > 0.7

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `raster layer unique values report`  with a little further processing?

Comment: @Erik Do you know any link that I can refer to on how to add process in the report? I just start to learn the QGIS only a little while. Will try it out

Comment: You know about the QGIS toolbox? And you know about the official QGIS tutorial?

Comment: @Erik not really. I only search in youtube for video that teach specific function I need. Can you recommend?

Comment: Yeah, I can recommend the official QGIS tutorial.